# How do I send a photo to telegram channel with telegram bot?

Tags: php, photo, channel, telegram-bot

I can send a photo to telegram chat with chat id using this code:

```
<?php
     $bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token-bot>/";
     $ch = curl_init($bot_url.'SendPhoto');
     $cfile = new CURLFile(realpath('file.png'),'image/png','photo.png');
     $data = array(
         'chat_id' => '118186395',
         'photo' => $cfile ,
         'caption' => 'testing'
     );
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

But if I change the `chat_id` value to the id of my channel, I receive an empty answer from telegram and the photo is not sent.

Comment: Are you sure your bot is an admin of the channel you are trying to send to?

Comment: yes because i can send message bot i can not send photo.

Answer (score 0):

Your channel should be public and `chat_id` must be in the format `@channelusername`.

[Source](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)